# Extract EndDate from the StartDate column using SQL i.e two dates coming from the same column

Tags: sql, oracle

My present table structure is :

[image]

I want to calculate the time duration weighted average price for each product id for that day.

e.g.

Average Price for PA1 = (100*4 + 105*4 + 110*8 + 115*4) / 20

i.e Here price stays 100 for 4 hrs, 105 for 4 hrs, 110 for 8 hrs and 115 for 4 hrs (the closing time is midnight)

This below Oracle SQL will help create the table structure quickly, thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE ProductTable
(ID NUMBER(5), 
 ProdId varchar(7),
 StartDate DATE,
Price NUMBER(4));

INSERT INTO ProductTable (ID, ProdId, StartDate, Price)
VALUES (1, 'PA1', TO_DATE('2015/08/01 4:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi'), 100);
INSERT INTO ProductTable (ID, ProdId, StartDate, Price)
VALUES (2, 'PA1', TO_DATE('2015/08/01 8:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi'), 105)
;
INSERT INTO ProductTable (ID, ProdId, StartDate, Price)
VALUES (3, 'PA2', TO_DATE('2015/08/01 9:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi'), 120);
INSERT INTO ProductTable (ID, ProdId, StartDate, Price)
VALUES (4, 'PA1', TO_DATE('2015/08/01 12:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi'), 110)
;
INSERT INTO ProductTable (ID, ProdId, StartDate, Price)
VALUES (5, 'PA3', TO_DATE('2015/08/01 14:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi'), 150)
;
INSERT INTO ProductTable (ID, ProdId, StartDate, Price)
VALUES (6, 'PA2', TO_DATE('2015/08/01 15:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi'), 130)
;
INSERT INTO ProductTable (ID, ProdId, StartDate, Price)
VALUES (7, 'PA2', TO_DATE('2015/08/01 18:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi'), 125)
;
INSERT INTO ProductTable (ID, ProdId, StartDate, Price)
VALUES (8, 'PA1', TO_DATE('2015/08/01 20:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi'), 115)
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with x as (
  select
  prodid,
  price,
  nvl(lead(extract(hour from cast(startdate as timestamp)))
   over (partition by prodid order by startdate), 24)
   - extract(hour from cast(startdate as timestamp)) as timediff
  from producttable),
y as (
select 
prodid, 
sum(x.timediff*x.price) as sm,
sum(x.timediff) as stimediff
from x
group by prodid)
select prodid, sm / stimediff as weightedAvg_Price
from y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically want the `lead()` function and then some date arithmetic:

```
select prodid,
       sum((least(trunc(startdate + 1, next_startdate) - startdate)*24) numhours
from (select p.*, lead(startdate) over (order by startdate) as next_startdate
      from producttable t
     ) t
where date = date '2015-08-01'
group by prodid;
```

This bases the calculation on the first record during the day, which is how you have described the results in the question.

Comment: Thank you, I understood the logic of using lead(). I am posting below a working code.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is simpler. However, you can also try this which uses `cte`s.

You should also decide if the weighted average has to be calculated for a given day for a prodid. In that case, it would require grouping on the day and year as well.

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f4e6/6

```
with x as (
select
 prodid
,price
,extract(hour from cast(startdate as timestamp))
 -nvl(lag(extract(hour from cast(startdate as timestamp))) 
 over(partition by prodid order by startdate),0) timediff
 from producttable)
, y as(
  select prodid, sum(x.timediff*x.price) as sm, sum(timediff) stimediff
  from x
  group by prodid)
  select prodid, sm / stimediff weighted_avg
  from y
```

Comment: Thank you, but I made few changes to your code to get what I needed. I have posted the code below.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this query below. This is specific to structure you mentioned

```
SELECT y.prodid,
       sum(y.price*y.hours_diff)/sum(hours_diff)
FROM
  (SELECT x.prodid,
          x.price,
          x.curr_prod_st_date,
          x.next_prod_st_date,
          round(to_char(to_date(x.next_prod_st_date,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'hh24.miss')-to_char(to_date(x.curr_prod_st_date,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'hh24.miss'),0)hours_diff
   FROM
     ( SELECT prod.*,
              to_char(prod.startdate,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')curr_prod_st_date,
              nvl(lead(to_char(prod.startdate,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),1) over (partition BY prodid
                                                                                 ORDER BY prodid,id,price),to_char(trunc(prod.startdate)+1-1/86400,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) next_prod_st_date
      FROM producttable prod)x)y
GROUP BY y.prodid
```